# how create Save as Dialog box in java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans

i had create a web application in which data report should be converted to pdf and excel then it should stored to a specific location. but i am specifying particular so that i will be stored automatically. But they want me to provide a save as dialog box to choose location i am confused how to add. i am using jsp as frontend mysql as backend pdf conversion connectivity all are done in servlet.

Answer (score 1):

The response containing the PDF binary stream should have the following header :

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=theFileName.pdf;
```

This will tell browsers to treat the PDF as an attachment, and the browser will open a Save As dialog box where the proposed file name is theFileName.pdf. You won't have any possibility to suggest a directory location, though.